# How to insert a line break between two inline-block elements?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how I can introduce a line break between these to div elements in the fiddle [**here**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/zh9h3594/show/).

The challenge here is that the elements needs to be centered, but also that I need to be able to force a line break. If I use float I can control the line breaking with:

```
.article:after {
   content: '\A';
   white-space: pre;
}
```

But then obviously the elements aren't centered anymore.

Here's a [**link**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/zh9h3594/light/) straight to the fiddle.

EDIT: I updated with a new fiddle to clarify the need for `display: inline-block`, hover over one of the images to see the overlay positioned over the image.

```
<div id="posts">
  <div class="article">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="overlay">
      </div>
      <div class="content photo">
        <img style="max-width: 45vw;" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
      </div>   
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="article">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="overlay">
      </div>
      <div class="content photo">
        <img style="max-width: 38vw;" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/ff0000/fff">
      </div>   
    </div>
  </div>          
</div>
```

```
#posts {
    text-align:center;
}

.article {
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.article:after {
    content: '\A';
    white-space: pre;
}

.article .inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: reverse;
    -moz-box-direction: reverse;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column-reverse;
    -ms-flex-direction: column-reverse;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.article .overlay {
    height: 101%;
    width: 101%;
    margin: 0 0 -25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color .3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: background-color .3s ease-out;
    transition: background-color .3s ease-out;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can U provide a GIF of your desired goal ? I can't understand what's is it

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/z94bzm4n/3/embedded/result/?

Comment: @j08691 Correct, but the display: inline-block is mandatory, so you can't just remove it.

Comment: Also, downvoter, please elaborate why you downvoted.

Comment: why not just wrap each row in a div ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making them `block` elements instead of `inline-block` would break the line and keep them centered:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/z94bzm4n/5/

```
.article {
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

That happens because the `.article` divs inherit the `text-align: center` from the parent div. Since images are inline elements, it causes them to be centered...

**EDIT**

Another solution, keeping the `inline-block` property is to increase the gap between the elements (since they're inline) using `word-spacing` on the parent. Setting it with a viewport unit (e.g. VW) would break the elements perfectly:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/z94bzm4n/7/

```
#posts {
    text-align: center;
    word-spacing: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I need the `display: inline-block;` or something that does exactly the same, see the fiddle in my updated question for the overlay effect (that's destroyed with `display: block`)

Comment: Just wanna come back here and say that this solution currently don't work in Safari. Neither in iOS or on OSX.